# How can I add persistence to Play Silhouette password hasher registry?

Tags: scala, playframework, passwords, persistence, silhouette

I'm looking at the Play Silhouette seed example:

https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-seed

It is clear how to add persistence to `UserDAO` and `AuthTokenDAO` because they have in memory implementations `UserDAOImpl` and `AuthTokenDAOImpl` which you can override and provide database implementations like `MongoUserDAOImpl` and `MongoAuthTokenDAOImpl`.

However I'm puzzled by where hashed passwords are stored. There is no DAO for this in the example.

This is the point where the user submits a registration password:

https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-seed/blob/master/app/controllers/SignUpController.scala#L80

```
val authInfo = passwordHasherRegistry.current.hash(data.password)
```

How can I add persistence to passwordHasherRegistry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to add persistence to `passwordHasherRegistry`. `passwordHasherRegistry` is an object that contains a list of current and historical hash functions used to hash the password so you can verify it.

According to the [Persistence docs page](https://www.silhouette.rocks/docs/persistence) to persist hashed password information you should provide implementation of `AuthInfoRepository` trait. You may use [`DelegableAuthInfoRepository`](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette/blob/0b32a4816f56dadf43c53a356a0601a96fe76c36/silhouette-persistence/src/main/scala/com/mohiva/play/silhouette/persistence/repositories/DelegableAuthInfoRepository.scala) that delegates the work to instance(s) of [`DelegableAuthInfoDAO`](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette/blob/0b32a4816f56dadf43c53a356a0601a96fe76c36/silhouette-persistence/src/main/scala/com/mohiva/play/silhouette/persistence/daos/DelegableAuthInfoDAO.scala). See also [Silhouette Persistence ReactiveMongo](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-persistence-reactivemongo/tree/4.0.0) GitHub repository that provides some Mongo-based implementation `MongoAuthInfoDAO`

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. I will look at the example you gave and I'm also looking at this article: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-playful-web-dev-1-trs-bluemix/. I hope I can put the pieces together.

Comment: @sbtpr, if you take closer look, you may notice that [`MongoAuthInfoDAO`](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-persistence-reactivemongo/blob/4.0.0/src/main/scala/com/mohiva/play/silhouette/persistence/daos/MongoAuthInfoDAO.scala) from the repository I mentioned is quite similar to `PasswordInfoDao` and `OAuth1InfoDao` in your example but the one on the GitHub seems more flexible in terms of configuration.

Comment: Thanks again, I managed to get the module working. I wrote an answer to show what lame mistakes one can commit while trying to get things going.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion by @SergGr I used https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-persistence-reactivemongo module to implement password persistence.

The documentation of the module shows how to construct a DAO instance:

```
val dao = new MongoAuthInfoDAO[PasswordInfo](reactiveMongoApi, config)
```

The original example binds DAO as follows:

```
bind[DelegableAuthInfoDAO[PasswordInfo]].toInstance(new InMemoryAuthInfoDAO[PasswordInfo])
```

It is tempting to simply replace this with

```
bind[DelegableAuthInfoDAO[PasswordInfo]].toInstance(new MongoAuthInfoDAO[PasswordInfo](reactiveMongoApi, config))
```

and try to inject the required parameters as

```
class SilhouetteModule @Inject() (reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi, configuration: Configuration) extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule
```

This will compile, and it seems that it makes sense. However this will result in a runtime error, because the injection cannot be performed. It seems we are trying to inject something before having set up the injector correctly.

The solution is to remove this binding alltogether and rely solely on

```
@Provides
def providePasswordInfoDAO(reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi, config: Configuration): DelegableAuthInfoDAO[PasswordInfo] = {
  implicit lazy val format = Json.format[PasswordInfo]
  new MongoAuthInfoDAO[PasswordInfo](reactiveMongoApi, config)
}
```

This is in the documentation but it is not emphasized that you should use this *instead* of trying to create an instance yourself.

On little caveat is that the implementation creates a collection `auth.PasswordInfo` and if you try to check it in the mongo shell with `db.auth.PasswordInfo.find()`, you will get an error. The dot in the name is a problem, so you have to use `db["auth.PasswordInfo"].find()`.